# using hibernate 5 how to create a table with a ROW at the time of first execution?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

i want to insert a row in a table as with table creation time but Hibernate 5 is create table successfully but not insert my given default row like below example,

i already tried below code,

```
@Entity
public class FTPDomain {
@Id
private Long id=(long)1;

private String transferCroneTime="0 0 0 29 2 ?";

private String cleanCroneTime="0 0 0 29 2 ?";

//Setters & Getters
}
```

and i also tried ,

```
 @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if(id == null) id = (long)1;
        if(transferCroneTime == null) transferCroneTime ="0 0 0 29 2 ?";
        if(cleanCroneTime == null) cleanCroneTime = "0 0 0 29 2 ?"
    }
```

> i expect when FTPDomain.java compile and execute first time create table with a ROW where id=1, transferCroneTime=0 0 0 29 2 ? and cleanCroneTime=0 0 0 29 2 ? in the table.

Thanks...

Comment: Your expectation is just unrealistic. That won't happen. If you want some application to create an instance of an entity and persist it, you need to write that code. Hibernate won't guess your intentions and do it for you.

Comment: Thank to reply, i alredy used @PrePersist but it also not create ROW in my table. please see edited question.

Comment: PrePersist is a hook that is called every time you persist an entity of that type. Remove that. Again:  Hibernate won't persist any entity for you.

Comment: Dear, So how to add a row at time of table creation in this situation.

Comment: I use FlywayDB or Liquibase to create (and prepopulate if needed) my database schema. It's the best solution, that you can use in production too (unlike hibernate's automatic table creation). If you still want to keep using hibernate to create your tables, and want some data to be inserted, then write the code to insert that data and execute it when your application starts.

Answer (score 0):

@PrePersist and @PreUpdate are JPA event listener, which are meant to modify entity states before the entity gets persisted or updated, as already mentioned in the comments. See the following examples for a proper usage of these event listeners.

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
   creationDate = Localdatetime.now();
   updatedDate = Localdatetime.now();
} 

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
   updatedDate = Localdatetime.now();
}
```

If you want to pre-populate data to a freshly created schema, then you need to use the mechanisms described in this article https://thoughts-on-java.org/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/, whereby you configure it in your persistence.xml via the parameter **javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source**, which points to a sql script which loads the data via insert statements into your database.

There are also hibernate specific properties which provide the same functionality as describe in the docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_importing_script_files, but I would recommend to use the JPA specific ones.